# Connecting Firebase with Python getting error

Tags: python, macos, firebase

I am using a MacBook pro and I am trying to use the Firebase realtime database with Python so I installed the package:

```
$ sudo pip install requests==1.1.0
$ sudo pip install python-firebase
```

It seems like it successfully installed in the terminal but when I run the python code:

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myfirebaseURL.firebaseio.com', None)
result = firebase.get('/users', None)
print (result)
```

I get an error saying that "...from firebase import firebase
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase'"

Any advice or comments would be really helpful.

Comment: What version of pip and python are you using?  Edit your question to include the output of `sudo pip --version` and `python --version`.

Comment: I am using python 3.7 and pip 2.7.

Comment: That would be the problem.  Pip is installing packages for python version 2, but you're using python 3.  Does your system have a `pip3` command?

Comment: I see. Should I uninstall python3 and install python 2? Sorry but I am not sure what meant by 'pip3'

Comment: On some systems, `pip3` is a separate version of pip that specifically works with python 3.

Comment: I changed my python to 2.7 and reinstalled the package and it works fine! Thanks so much!!